# How can I make my images to loop in a random order?

Tags: javascript

I know math.random() option exists but I'm not able to figure out how to use it in my code. Currently, it is looping in a sorted manner.

```
(function () {
  var rotator = document.getElementById("rotator"); // change to match image ID
  var imageDir =
    "/Users/loh/Documents/ElectronJS/newapp1/newapp1/pages/images/visionboard/";
  var delayInSeconds = 1;
  var num = 0;
  let currentIndex = 0;
  const totalImages = 16;
  const changeImage = function () {
    num = ++num % totalImages;
    rotator.src = imageDir  + num + ".png";
  };
  setInterval(changeImage, delayInSeconds * 1000);
})();
```

Comment: so `Math.floor(Math.random() * totalImages)` if you do not want repeats, then it is more work.

Answer (score 2):

```
(function () {
  var rotator = document.getElementById("rotator"); // change to match image ID        
  var imageDir =
    "/Users/loh/Documents/ElectronJS/newapp1/newapp1/pages/images/visionboard/";
  var delayInSeconds = 1;
  var num = 0;
  let currentIndex = 0;
  const totalImages = 16;
  const changeImage = function () {
    var incre = Math.floor(Math.random() * (totalImages-1) ) + 1;
    num += incre;
    num = num % totalImages;
    rotator.src = imageDir  + num + ".png";
  };
  setInterval(changeImage, delayInSeconds * 1000);
})();
```

Comment: not sure why someone downvoted your answer but this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! :)

Comment: I realized it could be var incre = Math.floor(Math.random() * (totalImages-1) ) + 1; and by doing this the while loop is not required. Yeah, solution edited.